# Why does this script not loop/only runs once?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, while-loop

This is a simple Pomodoro timer I wrote. Theoretically, it will run itself infinitely, alternating between timing for 25 minutes and 5 minutes.

```
import time
import sys
import datetime
import winsound

def ring(sound):
    winsound.PlaySound('%s.wav' % sound, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

times = 0

while True:
    tomato = 0
    while tomato <= 1500:
        timeLeft = 1500 - tomato
        formatted = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeLeft))
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+ formatted)
        time.sleep( 1 )
        tomato += 1
    ring("MetalGong")

    fun = 0
    while fun <= 300:
        funTimeleft = 300 - fun
        funFormatted = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=funTimeleft))
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+ funFormatted)
        time.sleep( 1 )
        fun +=1
    ring("AirHorn")

    times += 1
    print("You have completed" + times + "Pomodoros.")
```

But, it only got through one go; as soon as it finished the 5 minute block, the console window closed (I had run it directly by a double-click, instead of through a terminal).

Why would it close like that? Does it have something to do with how I used `while True:`?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: if you run it from the console you will see you very quickly why.... well in about 5 minutes

Comment: looks like its failing at this 'winsound.PlaySound('%s.wav' % sound, winsound.SND_FILENAME)' line. Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future try running it from a console so you can see the traceback it generates when an exception is raised.

```
print("You have completed" + times + "Pomodoros.")
```

You can't implicitly concatenate `int`s and strings.  This throws a `TypeError` and thus ends your program.

To fix:

```
print("You have completed " + str(times) + " Pomodoros.") # this works, and is ugly

print("You have completed {} Pomodoros.".format(times)) # better.
```